# SVG single curved corner square / rectangle

Tags: svg

I have this SVG image which I want to add curved corners to.

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 width="1024px" height="768px" viewBox="0 0 1920 1080" enable-background="new 0 0 1920 1080" xml:space="preserve">

<rect x="0" y="0" fill="#e85c78" width="45" height="45"/>
<rect x="45" y="0" fill="#e2235d" width="45" height="45"/>

<rect x="0" y="45" fill="#75bae5" width="45" height="45"/>
<rect x="45" y="45" fill="#3ca8de" width="45" height="45"/>

<rect x="0" y="90" fill="#fac06b" width="45" height="45"/>
<rect x="45" y="90" fill="#f6b043" width="45" height="45"/>

<rect x="0" y="135" fill="#76b65e" width="45" height="45"/>
<rect x="45" y="135" fill="#3ea73d" width="45" height="45"/>

<rect x="0" y="180" fill="#456b7e" width="45" height="45"/>
<rect x="45" y="180" fill="#0d5065" width="45" height="45"/>

<rect x="32.5" y="225" fill="#d4c8b3" width="12.5" height="100"/>
<rect x="45" y="225" fill="#bfb299" width="12.5" height="100"/>
```

The first rectangle should have the top left corner curved, the second rectangle should the top right corner curved, the penultimate rectangle should have the bottom left corner curved, and the last rectangle should have the bottom right corner curved.

I have tried using paths, but they don't make sense, and the long goal is show and and hide each rectangle in a loop, and this seems complicated with paths.

Can anyone enlighten in doing single corner curves?

Comment: I'm not completely sure about making specific corners round but I do know that to make the corners round you just need to change the `x` and `y` to `rx` and `ry`.

You could also give d3 a shot. I've done something similar to what you're explaining with it.

Answer (score 2):

You can't control the radius of an individual corner. If you're just working with solid filled rectangles, then you could instead draw a rounded rect and place a square at each corner. You can then show and hide these squares to simulate corners with and without rounding:

```css
svg rect { fill: #e85c78; }
svg .A, svg:hover .B { opacity:1; }
svg .B, svg:hover .A { opacity:0; }
```

```html
<svg width="160" height="160" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
  <rect x="10" y="10" width="140" height="140" rx="50" ry="50"/>
  <rect x="10" y="10" width="50" height="50" class="A"/>
  <rect x="100" y="10" width="50" height="50" class="B"/>
  <rect x="100" y="100" width="50" height="50" class="A"/>
  <rect x="10" y="100" width="50" height="50" class="B"/>
</svg>
```